# Replace everything after some random words

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi how can i replace everything after some random words

EX:

```
text/col_det/keywords
text/col_ret/excalibur
text/col_get/random
text/col_free/read
```

So all will become

```
text/col_det/
text/col_ret/
text/col_get/
text/col_free/
```

Tried this but not working

Find what:

```
text/col_(.*?)/.*
```

Replace with:

```
    Blank
```

Comment: Personally if I were on Linux I'd use grep/sed to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi thanks but how to do it on Linux because i tried using this command but it grep everytihng from the file cat words.txt | grep -i text > result.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then it should work if you change the regex to replace into

```
text/col_\1/
```

`\1` is the text between the brackets inside the regex you searched for.

Comment: @cton453 For me it works just fine (Notepad 6.2.3). Did you check the `Regular expression` in the Search mode options?

Comment: Yes but nothing replaced using Notepad++ v6.3

Comment: @cton453 Just installed newest Notepad++ 6.3.1 and it works as well for me. Strange that it does not for you. See http://imgur.com/f1Nhtfn,gLIClVT#0 and http://imgur.com/f1Nhtfn,gLIClVT#1 for screenshots before and after replacing with your example text provided.

Comment: Oh nooo I misunderstood you...yes it works i put text/col_\1/ in the Find what: and leave the Replace with: blank, thats why it is not working now everything working just fine :D

Answer (score 0):

`text/col_(.*?)/.*` matches the whole line, replacing it with nothing will clear the line.

This should work:

Replace

```
^text/col_(.*?)/.*$
```

with

```
text/col_\1/
```

`^` - start of line
`$` - end of line
`\1` - (basically) the matching string for first thing you put in brackets, so whatever was matched from `(.*?)` in this case.

Start and end of line is probably optional in this case.

Remember to select the search mode to be Regular Expressions.

Comment: @cton453 Are you running Notepad++ 6 or above? I believe there were some issues with regex before 6 (not sure about the specific details).